# Why is Informatica lookup returning NULL when all conditions are true?

Tags: lookup, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am using a connected lookup to get a value when match conditions are found. However, the lookup is returning NULL value when in database a non NULL value is present.

I have verified in Informatica Debugger and the database that all the conditions are matching and there is corresponding value is present.

Here are the screenshots: -

Debugger: - (I noticed a little red exclamation mark on the lookup port, I am not sure what does it signify)

Onerosity Tag is the lookup value. Lookup condition used in Ports 2 to 7

[Informatica_Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEXKr.png)

Informatica Verbose Mode Logs: -

[Verbose_Mode Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QatXN.png)

Lookup Table data: -
[Lookup_Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERalB.png)

Result when I use join in SQL: -
[SQL Join](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ikGv.png)
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuSWn.png)

It seems like there is some minor change I need to make but I am not able to figure out what it would be.

Comment: `Onerosity_Tag` is the name of the table and the field in that table. I don't know how, but it could cause Informatica to generate an invalid query. Could you check the generated SQL query for the Lookup in the session log ? (And add it to the question if possible) You could try to execute this query to see if the database returns what you expect.

Comment: There might be trailing spaces in Product name or other string columns in the lookup table. Just a guess. Try doing a trim in lookup override query.

Comment: Can you please add a query created for the lookup? Can you show all lookup ports and conditions? I can't see the input / output ports.

Comment: Would  be interesting to see the mapping editor view to check how the ports have been linked from the pipeline to the lookup transformation and whether the port has been listed as an input or output port

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved and if was because one of the LKP values was a CHAR attribute in the LKP table and not a VARCHAR.

I got below comment from community member to fix this issue.

"
The difference is subtle but mean:

A CHAR value is always padded to its defined maximum length with blank spaces.

Now when you run a SQL query (as in your example), then the SQL interpreter of (in your case) SQL Server will automatically "pad" the values which are too short to the correct defined length, meaning a SQL query run manually will return what you are looking for.

However, the LKP transformation runs a SELECT query to get all lookup records from the database. And in this case all CHAR attributes are padded to their defined maximum length.

If you now feed e.g. a lookup value '123' into the LKP transformation and the underlying lookup table has a CHAR(5) for this attribute, then the LKP cache will contain the string '123  ' in its index cache. But you are asking for a lookup value of '123'. Clearly '123' and '123  ' do not match, meaning you get no results.
"

Answer (score 0):

Check your lookup override query/data type of the onerosity port in lookup.

Comment: There is no lookup override query in the mapping and the Onerosity data type is String. Would data type of this port impact the output?

Answer (score 0):

2 ways to solve this problem:

1. Either trim --ltrim(rtrim(value_here)) the values from your workflow and database, so they can match
2. You have to pad the space to both your mapping value and the lookup value, so it can match.